# Tree. Delete node, but pass its children to a parent node

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, dictionary, tree

I'm trying to traverse an arbitrary tree and build a new tree, which would delete certain nodes, but connect their children to parent nodes. I don't want to use a recursion or classes, only lists, dictionaries, etc. [image]

Below is the code that does half of the job - it traverses the original tree and tries to build a new tree, but I just can't wrap my mind around building a new tree using a stack.

```py
original_tree = {
    'id': 1,
    'children': [
        {
            'id': 2,
            'children': [{'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'children': [
                {'id': 6, 'children': [{'id': 7}]},
                {'id': 8, 'delete': True, 'children': [{'id': 9}, {'id': 10}]},
                {'id': 11}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

stack = [original_tree]
new_tree = {}

while len(stack):
    node = stack.pop(0)
    print(node['id'])
    children = node.get('children', [])

    # === Start building a new tree ===
    if not node.get('delete'):
        new_tree['id'] = node['id']
        pass
    # ================================

    for i in range(len(children) - 1, -1, -1): 
        stack.insert(0, children[i])
```

Comment: Rather than checking if the current node must be deleted, you should instead check which of its children must be deleted and then connect it to its grand children.  In your example, when processing 5, you first loop through its children, see that 8 must be deleted and then append 9 and 10 to 5's children.  Besides, why not use recursion?

Comment: What if the root node had the `delete` attribute? Which would be the root of the resulting tree then?

Comment: @qouify, i looked through some of the recursive tree traversal algorithms and thought that they were even more convoluted than loop-based approaches  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @trincot, good question, but in my case that would never happen. I forgot to mention that

Comment: In fact, I believe a recursive solution would look much more elegant ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a stack, you lose the link between parent and child — there's no way to know if the next item you pop off the stack is a sibling or parent. You can fix that by keep track of parents as you add items to the stack. Then when you pop an item from the stack you have a reference to the parent node.

To handle deletes, you only need to add the deleted children to the stack with the correct parent reference. Here's a quick example:

```
original_tree = {
    'id': 1,
    'children': [
        {
            'id': 2,
            'children': [{'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'children': [
                {'id': 6, 'children': [{'id': 7}]},
                {'id': 8, 'delete': True, 'children': [{'id': 9}, {'id': 10}]},
                {'id': 11}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

stack = [{'parent': None, 'node':original_tree}]
root = None

while len(stack):
    frame = stack.pop()

    node = frame['node']
    parent = frame['parent']
    
    # Allocate a new node
    new_node = {'id': node['id']}
    
    # Append the node to the parent if there is one; there won't be one for the root
    if parent is not None:
        if not node.get('delete'):
            parent.setdefault('children',[]).append(new_node)
    else:
        root = new_node
        
    children = node.get('children', [])

    print(node['id'])

    for child in reversed(children): 
        if child.get('delete'):
            # to delete a child, you need to add its children to the stack
            grand_children = child.get('children', [])
            for grand_child in reversed(grand_children):
                stack.append({'parent': new_node, 'node':grand_child})
        else:
            stack.append({'parent': new_node, 'node':child})
```

Printing the new tree `root` gives you:

```
{'id': 1,
 'children': [{'id': 2, 'children': [{'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]},
  {'id': 5,
   'children': [{'id': 6, 'children': [{'id': 7}]},
    {'id': 9},
    {'id': 10},
    {'id': 11}]}]}
```

Where the children of deleted node `8` and now children of `5`.

(also, with python lists, it's more efficient to pop and append off the end: `pop()` & `append()` rather than `insert(0)` and `pop(0)`)

Comment: fantastic! Thank you :)

Comment: @Mark : note that this does not work if the tree has two consecutive nodes (a father and its son) that must be deleted.  For example if 9 must be deleted, then this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @qouify -- I think it's a simple matter of just checking the `delete` status before appending it. I've edited the answer.